# Is there a geometric way of showing this?

Tags: vectors

Q. Given that $u + v + w = 0$, show that $u × v = v × w = w × u $

($u, v$ and $w$ are vectors and $×$ is the cross product)

I have already shown it algebraically but wanted to know if there was a geometric way of looking at it also.

Comment: Why don't you use LaTeX?

Comment: @markvs because I have no idea how to

Comment: You may want to learn. It is easy and useful not only in Math. SE.

Comment: Please write an *informative* title—one that relates to the content of your question.

Answer (score 2):

If $u+v+w=0$, then $u,v,w$ (joined end-to-end) form the edges of a triangle, with one vertex at $O$.

In such a case, all three quantities $\frac12 (u \times v)$, $\frac12 (v \times w)$, $\frac12 (w \times u)$ (the order is important!) compute the *vector area* of this triangle.

You may object and say "How do you know those three cross products are equal to the vector area? What if you can't prove that geometrically?" - I'll give a geometric proof of that if you tell me how you define $a \times b$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $u+v+w=0$ the three vectors form the three sides of a triangle.

Call the angles opposite the vectors, respectively $\theta_u,\theta_v,\theta_w$.

Then, using the Law of Sines we have

$$ \frac{\sin\theta_u}{|u|}=\frac{\sin\theta_v}{|v|}=\frac{\sin\theta_w}{|w|}$$

Multiply by $|u||v||w|$ to get

$$ |v||w|\sin \theta_u=|u||w|\sin \theta_v=\|u||v|\sin\theta_w$$

Thus the moduli of the cross products are the same.

Using the right-hand rule for the direction of cross-product, the three cross products are parallel in the same sense.

Thus,

$$ v\times w=u\times w=u\times v$$

Comment: That's a modulus equality, not a vector equality: you just showed that $\mid v \times w \mid = \mid u \times w \mid = \mid u \times v \mid$

Comment: @TannySieben You're right, I left out the fact that the crossed vectors are parallel.